# Failed to deploy Cloud Functions after upgrading to node 14

Tags: google-cloud-functions

After bumping the node version on my Firebase project from node 10 to node 14 in my package.json, like so:

```
...
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
...
```

Firebase throws an error whenever I try to deploy a function.

First, I run:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:foo
```

Afterwards, the console shows:

```
i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> lint
> gts lint

version: 14
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run build

> build
> ttsc

✔  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  functions: ensuring required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  functions: required API cloudbuild.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: required API cloudfunctions.googleapis.com is enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...
i  functions: packaged functions (257.54 KB) for uploading
i  pubsub: ensuring required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled...
i  scheduler: ensuring required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled...
✔  pubsub: required API pubsub.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  scheduler: required API cloudscheduler.googleapis.com is enabled
✔  functions: functions folder uploaded successfully
i  functions: updating Node.js 14 function foo(us-central1)...
✔  functions[foo(us-central1)]: Successful upsert schedule operation. 

Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        foo(us-central1)

To try redeploying those functions, run:
    firebase deploy --only "functions:foo"

To continue deploying other features (such as database), run:
    firebase deploy --except functions

Error: Functions did not deploy properly.
```

Unfortunately, there's not much logs that I can get from the error:

By running:

```
firebase deploy --only functions:foo
```

I get the following error logs:

> {"code":3,"message":"Build failed: > sharp@0.28.3 install /workspace/node_modules/sharp\n> (node install/libvips && node install/dll-copy && prebuild-install) || (node install/can-compile && node-gyp rebuild && node install/dll-copy)\n\nsharp: Downloading [https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.6/libvips-8.10.6-linux-x64.tar.br\n\n>](https://github.com/lovell/sharp-libvips/releases/download/v8.10.6/libvips-8.10.6-linux-x64.tar.br%5Cn%5Cn%3E) protobufjs@6.10.2 postinstall /workspace/node_modules/protobufjs\n> node scripts/postinstall\n\n\n> functions@undefined prepare /workspace\n> npm run compile\n\n\n> functions@ compile /workspace\n> ttsc\n\nsh: 1: ttsc: not found\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! syscall spawn\nnpm ERR! file sh\nnpm ERR! errno ENOENT\nnpm ERR! functions@ compile: `ttsc`\nnpm ERR! spawn ENOENT\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the functions@ compile script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_cacache/_logs/2021-06-06T04_27_25_637Z-debug.log\nnpm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE\nnpm ERR! errno 1\nnpm ERR! functions@undefined prepare: `npm run compile`\nnpm ERR! Exit status 1\nnpm ERR! \nnpm ERR! Failed at the functions@undefined prepare script.\nnpm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.\n\nnpm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:\nnpm ERR!     /builder/home/.npm/_logs/2021-06-06T04_27_25_673Z-debug.log; Error ID: beaf8772"}

In addition, my node version is:

```
node --version

v14.17.0
```

Comment: If you try to run your code in local with NodeJS 14, does this work well?

Comment: Yes. The code gets built and runs well on a local emulator. Unfortunately, deploying in the cloud fails during the build phase. I was able to fix it by removing the `ttypescript` and `sharp` dependencies. Still, I'm not sure why these dependencies works locally but fails to build in the cloud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After looking at the [Cloud Build](https://cloud.google.com/build?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&utm_campaign=japac-PH-all-en-dr-bkws-all-pkws-trial-e-dr-1009882&utm_content=text-ad-none-none-DEV_c-CRE_396437752289-ADGP_Hybrid%20%7C%20BKWS%20-%20EXA%20%7C%20Txt%20%7E%20Containers%20%7E%20Cloud%20Build_cloud%20build-getting%20started%20-%20Products-KWID_43700049544613562-kwd-838814262418&userloc_9066824-network_g&utm_term=KW_google%20cloud%20build%20console&gclid=Cj0KCQjwh_eFBhDZARIsALHjIKcxeJBBnbU74cCKwE3XF_wk9zjeQLdsxTFGbG3rblWm0cZ_yTe4XkAaAhNhEALw_wcB&gclsrc=aw.ds) from the Google Cloud Console, I've noticed that the following error:

> 2021-06-07T03:28:00.714478581ZStep #4 - "builder": src/cloud_functions/userInfo/https/onCall/uploadAvatar.ts(4,19): error TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'sharp'. '/workspace/node_modules/sharp/lib/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.

To fix this, I simply added the following code in the tsconfig.json:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "noImplicitAny": false,
        ...
    },
    ...
}
```